# Busqueda por nombre que hace no poder edirtar, detallar o eliminar campos

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estoy desarrollando un directorio que requiere busqueda por nombre, editar, ver detalles y eliminar registros de una base de datos desde la pagina, use las plantillas que vienen en visual studio para el crud pero el problema vino que al agregar el codigo de la busqueda hace que el id tomado al editar sea igual a 0 en vez de traer el id de el registro, necesito saber que puedo hacer para que funcionen ambos
Este es mi codigo de la busqueda y para mostrar todos los registros:

```
[HttpGet]
public ViewResult Index(string searchString = "")

{


    List<directorio> direct = new List<directorio>();



    string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection2"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);

    string sqlquery = "select * from [dbo].[directorio] WHERE Nombre like @searchString";

    SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);

    sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@searchString", SqlDbType.VarChar);

    sqlcomm.Parameters["@searchString"].Value = "%" + searchString + "%";

    sqlconn.Open();

    SqlDataReader sdr = sqlcomm.ExecuteReader();


    while (sdr.Read())

    {

        directorio uc = new directorio();

        uc.Nombre = sdr["Nombre"].ToString();
        uc.I = sdr["I"].ToString();
        uc.Linea = sdr["Linea"].ToString();
        uc.Depto = sdr["Depto"].ToString();
        uc.Ext = sdr["Ext"].ToString();
        uc.Directo = sdr["Directo"].ToString();
        uc.Abreviado = sdr["Abreviado"].ToString();
        uc.Usando355 = sdr["Usando355"].ToString();
        uc.Celular = sdr["Celular"].ToString();
        uc.Skype = sdr["Skype"].ToString();
        uc.Email = sdr["Email"].ToString();

        direct.Add(uc);


    }
    return View(direct);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

El primer planteo que puedo realizar es que el LIKE no se implementa de esa forma, sino que se unen los comodines dentro de la query y no en el parametro

```
string sqlquery = "select * from [dbo].[directorio] WHERE Nombre like '%' + @searchString + '%'";
SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);
sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchString", searchString);
```

Relacionado con el Id=0 en el edicion no veo que estes asignando la propiedad en la entidad `directorio`, pero si lo haces seguramente se deba a que no pasas esto por parametros cuando seleccionas la edicion

[View in ASP.NET MVC](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/mvc-view)

[Create Edit View in ASP.NET MVC](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/create-edit-view-in-asp.net-mvc)

si analizas el articulo veras que usa en la view

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.StudentId })
```

De esta forma el controles de edicion recibira como parte de la url el id como lo refleja en la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]